# How to check in linux kernel at vfs layer whether the file object is for a directory or a file

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, vfs

How to check in linux kernel at vfs layer whether the file object is for a directory or a file?

I have found that there is a function called `is_dx(dir)` which checks for this but it is present in `namei.c` in `ext3` or `ext4`. I need to do this at **vfs layer that** is independent of the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having in hand the inode of the initial directory, the code

examines the entry matching the first name to get the

corresponding inode.

q Then the directory file having that node is read from disk and

the entry matching the second name is examined to derive the

corresponding inode.

q This procedure is repeated for each name included in the path.

The dentry cache considerably speeds up the procedure

File system operations are mostly done at the dcache level , so

they are all under kernel lock.

Answer (score 2):

How about the `S_ISDIR()` macro defined in `include/linux/stat.h`? It takes`inode->i_mode` field to check if the  inode in question belongs to a directory or a file.