# How to judge an inode is a directory or mot in linux kernel

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel

I am working with Android 6.0 kernel, whose version is Linux 3.10. Now I wanna search all the inodes under a ext2 filesystem and judge wheather each of them is a directory or a file(such as a txt file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in linux kernel at vfs layer whether the file object is for a directory or a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168966/how-to-check-in-linux-kernel-at-vfs-layer-whether-the-file-object-is-for-a-direc)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that it is S_ISDIR telling me the inode is a directory or a regular file.